# curl problem, can't download full web page

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

With this code I'm trying to download this web page: [http://www.kayak.com/s/...](http://www.kayak.com/s/search/air?ai=kayaksample&do=y&ft=ow&ns=n&cb=e&pa=1&l1=ZAG&t1=a&df=dmy&d1=4/10/2010&depart_flex=exact&r1=y&l2=LON&t2=a&d2=11/10/2010&return_flex&r2=y)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.kayak.com/s/search/air?ai=kayaksample&do=y&ft=ow&ns=n&cb=e&pa=1&l1=ZAG&t1=a&df=dmy&d1=4/10/2010&depart_flex=exact&r1=y&l2=LON&t2=a&d2=11/10/2010&return_flex&r2=y');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,"http://wwww.google.com"); 

 $content = curl_exec ($ch);
 echo $content;
```

You can see the demo at: http://www.pointout.org/test.php
As you can see the part with prices is missing.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work the way you think it will. The reason is the prices are not in the initial HTML response that you get. Rather, there is some Javascript magic occurring which is using AJAX to load the prices when the page is loaded.

Comment: Yes but how httrack (http://www.httrack.com/) downloads this web page, works perfect.

Comment: This is because httrack is doing more than just loading the page using cURL. httrack is also parsing the HTML it loads and then fetching all additional resources, such as images, external Javascript etc.